# SAML2 Idp Metadata generation with .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, saml, saml-2.0

Net Framework library for SAML2 assertion. I was able to create SAML2 xml using .net libraries. But my requirement now is to generate metadata of that SAML2 assertion to give to client for their development. Is there any .net framework method to generate SAML2 metadata from SAML assertion object?

I have used System.IdentityModel.Tokens Saml2Assertion() class for SAML assertion.
I know there is a .net library to create metdata i.e System.IdentityModel.Metadata and to create EntityDescriptor from this library. But I dont want to manully create metadata as well. Ideally as per my understanding SAML2 metadata should be generated from SAML assertion xml/object without any manual intervention. Just wanted to check is there any way to this is with any .net library as I couldnt fine it anywhere.

I am using .net Framework - 4.8
Code for assertion :

```
private static Saml2Assertion createSamlAssertion()
    {
        // Here we create some SAML assertion with ID and Issuer name. 
        Saml2NameIdentifier nameidentifier = new Saml2NameIdentifier("XXX");
        Saml2Assertion assertion = new Saml2Assertion(nameidentifier);
        assertionid = "SamlAssertion-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        assertion.Id = new Saml2Id(assertionid);            
        assertion.Issuer = new Saml2NameIdentifier("XXXX");
        assertion.IssueInstant = Framework.ApplicationTime.GetCurrentTime();

        // Create some SAML subject. 

        Saml2SubjectConfirmation subcon = new Saml2SubjectConfirmation(new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"));
        subcon.Method = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer");
        subcon.NameIdentifier = new Saml2NameIdentifier("XXXX");
        Saml2SubjectConfirmationData subcondata = new Saml2SubjectConfirmationData();
        subcondata.NotBefore = GetCurrentTime();
        subcondata.NotOnOrAfter = GetCurrentTime().AddMinutes(60);
        subcon.SubjectConfirmationData = subcondata;
        Saml2Subject samlSubject = new Saml2Subject(subcon);
        
        samlSubject.NameId = new Saml2NameIdentifier("XXXX");


        assertion.Subject = samlSubject;

        // 
        // Create one SAML attribute with few values. 

        // Now create the SAML statement containing one attribute and one subject. 
        Saml2AttributeStatement samlAttributeStatement = new Saml2AttributeStatement();
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);

        attr = new Saml2Attribute("First Name");
        attr.Values.Add("JOHN");
        attr.Name = "First Name";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);

        attr = new Saml2Attribute("Name");
        attr.Values.Add("");
        attr.Name = "Name";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);


        attr = new Saml2Attribute("Street Name 1");
        attr.Values.Add("35 MAIN ST");
        attr.Name = "Street Name 1";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);

        attr = new Saml2Attribute("Street Name 2");
        attr.Values.Add("APT 204");
        attr.Name = "Street Name 2";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);

        attr = new Saml2Attribute("City Name");
        attr.Values.Add("LEXINGTON");
        attr.Name = "City Name";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);


        attr = new Saml2Attribute("Zip Code");
        attr.Values.Add("405117883");
        attr.Name = "Zip Code";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);

        attr = new Saml2Attribute("Contact Email Address");
        attr.Values.Add("john.doe@email.com");
        attr.Name = "Contact Email Address";
        attr.NameFormat = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
        samlAttributeStatement.Attributes.Add(attr);

        attributes = samlAttributeStatement.Attributes;

        // Append the statement to the SAML assertion. 
        assertion.Statements.Add(samlAttributeStatement);

        Saml2AuthenticationContext authcon = new Saml2AuthenticationContext();
        authcon.ClassReference = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password");
        Saml2AuthenticationStatement auth = new Saml2AuthenticationStatement(authcon);
        auth.AuthenticationInstant = GetCurrentTime();

        assertion.Statements.Add(auth);

        return assertion;           

    }
```

Comment: You want assertion or metadata? These are distinct notions.

Comment: I want metadata to be generated from assertion. I already have assertion xml.

Comment: You mean SAML token or the [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_metadata#Introduction_to_SAML_metadata)? Metadata is not related to the assertion. Rather, it only describes what your identity provider (or the service provider) does (like "here I am an identity provider, these are my services and these are my endpoints"). My guess is that you need a SAML token for the assertion, not the metadata but for some reason you refer to the SAML token as "metadata". Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the SAML [client-side libraries](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) do this.

I've used both Sustainsys and ComponentSpace to generate metadata.

Comment: Some time ago I've published another contestant, [OldMusicBox.Saml2](https://github.com/wzychla/OldMusicBox.Saml2) (MIT license). Supports basic client-side flows.

Comment: Is it possible for me to generate metadata using Sustainsys (or any other open source library) for the SAML assertion I have created using .net framework? If yes..could you please point me to code for reference.

Comment: The code and documents are in the references I gave.

Comment: Nice @WiktorZychla I'll add it to the list.

Comment: @rbrayb which reference are you talking about?

Comment: The link to the client-side libraries.

Comment: e.g. for Sustainsys - https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/951